# Magento Promotion code to apply 0 Tax and Specific Fixed Rate shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have a magento store.  I have two shipping options, fixed rate 1 and fixed rate 2.  I have a promotion code PROMO123, that gives a specific percentage off.  How do I go about creating a condition that is the following

```
if promo = "PROMO123"
 tax = 0
 shipping option is only fixed rate 2
```

I understand the code needs to be in PHP syntax, but where would be the right place to do this, or is this possible in the CMS.

Comment: I dont understand the promotion code you are trying to achieve? If PROMO123 & Shipping Option2 then set tax=0?

Comment: if the promo code is given, the only shipping option should be shipping option2 and tax = 0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? We are looking to do a similar thing. i.e. Use this coupon code and get $4.95 shipping.